# R - maximum value of variables when compared between levels of variable1 grouped by variable2

Tags: r, max, tidyverse, combn

Consider the following data

```
set.seed(123)

example.df <- data.frame( 
gene = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 100, replace = TRUE),
treated = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
resp=rnorm(100, 10,5), effect = rnorm (100, 25, 5))
```

I am trying to get the maximum value for all variables when they are compared by the levels of *gene* and grouped by *treated*. I can create the *gene* combinations like so,

```
combn(sort(unique(example.df$gene)), 2, simplify = T)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,] A    A    A    B    B    c   
#[2,] B    c    D    c    D    D   
#Levels: A B c D
```

Edit: The output I am looking for is a dataframe like this

```
comparison   group    max.resp    max.effect
A-B          no       value1      value2
....
C-D          no       valueX      valueY
A-B          yes      value3      value4 
.... 
C-D          yes      valueXX     valueYY
```

While I am able to get the max values for each individual *gene* level grouped by *treated*...

```
max.df <- example.df %>% 
           group_by(treated, gene) %>% 
           nest() %>% 
           mutate(mod = map(data, ~summarise_if(.x, is.numeric, max, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
           select(treated, gene, mod) %>% 
           unnest(mod) %>% 
           arrange(treated, gene)
```

Despite trying to tackle the issue for more than a day, I cannot figure out how to get the max for each numeric variable for each 2 level *gene*  comparison (**A vs B, A vs C, A vs D, B vs C, B vs D, and C vs D**) grouped by *treated*.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should use `set.seed` to guarantee reproducibility. Please also show the expected output based on a _minimal_ example.

Comment: I have done the recommended edits by removing unnecessary variables and providing a structure for the output I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, it might be a little messy, but I will update it in a better way, it takes no time whatsoever

```
library(tidyverse)
```

First I generate a dataframe with two columns, Gen1 and Gen2 for al possible comparisons, very similar to your use of `combn` but creating a data.frame

```
GeneComp <- expand.grid(Gen1 = unique(example.df$gene), Gen2 = unique(example.df$gene)) %>% filter(Gen1 != Gen2) %>% arrange(Gen1)
```

Then I loop throught it grouping by

```
Comps <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(GeneComp)){
  Comps[[i]] <- example.df %>% filter(gene == GeneComp[i,]$Gen1 | gene == GeneComp[i,]$Gen2) %>% # This line filters only the data with genes in the ith row
  group_by(treated) %>% # Then gorup by treated
  summarise_if(is.numeric, max) %>% # then summarise max if numeric
  mutate(Comparison = paste(GeneComp[i,]$Gen1, GeneComp[i,]$Gen2, sep = "-")) # and generate the comparisson variable
}

Comps <- bind_rows(Comps) # and finally join in a data frame
```

let me know if it does everything you want

### Adding in order to get only the data one time

It is important here that your genes are strings and not factors so you might have to do this

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

example.df <- data.frame( 
  gene = c(sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 100, replace = TRUE)),
  treated = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
  resp=rnorm(100, 10,5), effect = rnorm (100, 25, 5))
```

Then again in `expand.grid` add the `stringsAsFactors = F` argument

```
GeneComp <- expand.grid(Gen1 = unique(example.df$gene), Gen2 = unique(example.df$gene), stringsAsFactors = F) %>% filter(Gen1 != Gen2) %>% arrange(Gen1)
```

Now that allows you in the loop when pasting the **Comparisson** variable to sort both inputs, with that, the lines will be duplicated, but when you use the `distinct` function at the end, it will make your data the way you want it

```
Comps <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(GeneComp)){
    Comps[[i]] <- example.df %>% filter(gene == GeneComp[i,]$Gen1 | gene == GeneComp[i,]$Gen2) %>% # This line filters only the data with genes in the ith row
    group_by(treated) %>% # Then gorup by treated
    summarise_if(is.numeric, max) %>% # then summarise max if numeric
    mutate(Comparison = paste(sort(c(GeneComp[i,]$Gen1, GeneComp[i,]$Gen2))[1], sort(c(GeneComp[i,]$Gen1, GeneComp[i,]$Gen2))[2], sep = "-")) # and generate the comparisson variable
}

Comps <- bind_rows(Comps) %>% distinct() # and finally join in a data frame
```

Comment: I spent several hours over this, and had got to the point of figuring out I needed `expand.grid` in the solution. But what you have done is way more than what I currently know about R. You should consider creating a function to do this! Also, I need to look at doing this myself to improve my R skills, but can we remove the "duplicates", i.e *A-C,no* is the same as *C-A, no*?  Other than this, which will create two times the levels that are required, this is exactly what I was looking for to help me with a bunch of ggplots. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Ready @jaydoc when you say this is a needed function, is this something used often for gene analysis?

Comment: Thanks again. That works perfectly. I was trying to do this, so I could get the max values as a vector that I could then use to plot some significance values. IMHO, for something as simple as getting max or min values by pairwise comparisons, there ought to be a way to simply type in the variable(s) to be used as factors and getting summary stats by group.

Comment: Hello again @jaydoc, I think there are better ways to do this, instead of comparing the max, I have some ideas, I will invite you to a chatroom via Stackoverflow so that we might duscuss it